# What is title of this retro game with catchy fast techno-dance theme song?

Tags: pc, game-identification

My friend showed me a game installed on his PC back in 2006 and we captured the below eurodance-like song from it. Our paths diverged and I haven't spoken to him in years but I recently found the track again on my HDD.

The game was originally on a CD attached to a game magazine. I'm fairly certain it's the intro/theme music from that game, and that the game was for PC. I'd like to find out the game title.

I tried to google what games were attached there, but can't find the lists from all of them, we captured this song by Audacity, and this is all I have.

It seems to me (but do not remember a lot) it rather was a 2D game, and probably platform (maybe action takes place in space?). I am sure it was PC and no younger than 2006. It may be Japanese but I am not sure.

Comment: Do you know the magazine name?

Comment: @Robotnik no, there were a few Polish magazines with games. I found with archive.org and other sites lists from a few major (from period we did the recording - april 2006), but I didn't recognized this one (also looking on youtube for gameplays or OSTs).

Comment: I assume that, when you found this video, the title *wasn't* "Theme from Hyperballoid Deluxe"? Because I feel like that would have been a bit of a giveaway.

Comment: @F1Krazy nope, it is my video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. This is Hyperballoid Deluxe